# Libvirt/KVM vm - No network connectivity

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, openstack

I have installed devstack (OpenStacks development platform) on a physical ubuntu 14.04 host and I have been trying to follow the tutorials for [manually creating an image](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ubuntu-image.html). I have tried for Ubuntu and Windows but I'm having trouble connecting to any network in any VMs!

In particular the issues I'm facing in each OS are:

- In Windows I complete the Windows Server 2008 R2 installation (using the [RedHat VirtIO SCSI Driver](http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win)). However installing the network adapter from here results in a faulty ethernet adapter with a `Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware` error. I have tried multiple versions of these drivers including the latest and followed several threads in serverfault/superuser to remedy this but to no avail - however I think my problem might be something more basic as I also have the problem with Linux:
- In Ubuntu I cannot get outside to the internet. It cannot get an IP via DHCP. When I attempt to manually set the IP and gateway it also does not work.

I have tried running the command line `virt-install`, using the `virt-manager`, also just running `kvm` as [demonstrated here](https://www.openstack.org/summit/portland-2013/session-videos/presentation/windows-on-openstack-best-practices-and-pitfalls).

I have confirmed that the default network is running via `virsh net-list`. I have also tried creating my own virtual network forwarding to a different physical NIC on the host.

I feel like I must be missing something incredibly basic - seeing as Devstack is supposed to take care of everything for me. Is anyone able to shed some light on what I'm missing?

As I think someone will ask for it, below is my ifconfig output on the physical host. `eth1` was the original interface I setup. `br100` is the default via `ip route`. It has the IP address that I SSH to. `virbr1` I setup later with `eth1` to see if I could setup my own virtual NIC to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone is able to offer!

```
br100     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:6a:38:cf  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16:12ff:fec1:f0a6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:907152 errors:0 dropped:37287 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:423660 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:747967771 (747.9 MB)  TX bytes:342487377 (342.4 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:6a:38:ce  
          inet addr:10.2.3.235  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fe6a:38ce/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18049 errors:504072 dropped:3377 overruns:504071 frame:1
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1225147 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:900 (900.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:6a:38:cf  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fe6a:38cf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7586088 errors:62 dropped:125 overruns:61 frame:1
          TX packets:2869705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7508464333 (7.5 GB)  TX bytes:504000761 (504.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3472993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3472993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6684075053 (6.6 GB)  TX bytes:6684075053 (6.6 GB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:41:fb:f4:b3:f4  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:35:3d:e3  
          inet addr:10.2.3.1  Bcast:10.2.3.7  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5320 (5.3 KB)  TX bytes:126 (126.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:c7:ca:0e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fec7:ca0e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44521 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:22614 (22.6 KB)  TX bytes:2318324 (2.3 MB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:16:3e:05:ac:f2  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc16:3eff:fe05:acf2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:107942 (107.9 KB)  TX bytes:7140337 (7.1 MB)

vnet2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:67:ea:d2  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe67:ead2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:74 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:4560 (4.5 KB)  TX bytes:14532 (14.5 KB)

vnet3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:93:8b:54  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe93:8b54/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1034 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:6804 (6.8 KB)  TX bytes:53970 (53.9 KB)
```

Comment: Are you sure the network card is using virtio at all? Post a `virsh dumpxml $VM`

Comment: Thanks for the response. No - I'm not sure of this. What should I do if it's not? One of the arguments I am passing to kvm is `-net nic,model=virtio`. I've just shutdown this devstack instance and am rebuilding to make sure I've not missed something silly so I can't give you the output of that at the moment!

Comment: Have you been using nova networking or neutron?

Comment: Hi dyasny. I've been using nova as I thought that would be simplest. Is that wise? Here is a pastebin of your previous question - the virsh dumpxml http://pastebin.com/GdKwr5VN

Comment: The card seems to be virtio. Maybe your nova network isn't set up properly, it's basically a bridge